# Setting a union in c++ using Thrift

Tags: c++, thrift

I have something like this in my Thrift schema:

```
struct TestStatusOne { .... }
struct TestStatusTwo { .... }

union TestStatus {
  1: TestStatusOne  ONE
  2: TestStatusTwo  TWO
}

struct TestResult {
  1: required TestStatus status
}
```

I can define this fine using Java, Perl and Python libraries, but am
having trouble doing it with the C++ libraries. Here is an example in
Java:

```
TestResult testResult = new TestResult(
  new TestStatus(TestStatus._Fields.findByName("ONE"), testStatus)
);
```

The closest I have got to getting it defined in C++ is:

```
TestResult testResult;
testResult.status.ONE = testStatus;
```

But when I try to send to the server I get an error telling me the
status field is not present, and the dump of the structure shows it as
null.

How can I set the test status?

Using Thrift 0.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a problem of a missing assignment operator? Depending on the definition of the structs TestStatusOne and TestStatusTwo, you may need to create an assignment operator ( operator=() ).

Have you tried doing a GDB on the Thrift client and look at the contents of the testResult before sending it to the server? Check that its contents make sense.